# JavaScript - is all functions truthy

Tags: javascript

I have n number of functions, each one takes a 'data' {Object} as argument. Each function return a {Boolean} based on the given argument.

I want to compose/chain these functions, what is the best way to accomplish that?

See code below.

```
var fn1 = function(data) {
  return data.status === 404;
};
var fn2 = function(data) {
  return data.url === 'any_url';
};

var composed = compose(fn1, fn2);

// The line below must return false:
composed({ status: 404, url: 'foobar'});

// The line below must return true:
composed({ status: 404, url: 'any_url'});
```

Comment: Currying. [Great article on it](https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/)

Comment: just a little snippet: `var composeAnd = (a,b) => val => a(val) && b(val);` and `var composed = composeAnd(fn1, fn2);` or `var composed = [fn1, fn2].reduce(composeAnd);` where the Array can contain as many functions as you want to be concatenated by `&&`. Or a more versatile implementation: `var composeAnd = (a,b) => function(){ return a.apply(this, arguments) && b.apply(this, arguments) };`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to return `true` if all functions return `true`? That can be achieved with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). We simply use `Array#every` on the array of functions and return the function's result in the callback:

```
function compose() {
  var fns = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return function(obj) {
    return fns.every(function(f) {
      return f(obj);
    });
  };
}
```

```js
function compose() {
  var fns = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return function(obj) {
    return fns.every(function(f) {
      return f(obj);
    });
  };
}


var fn1 = function(data) {
  return data.status === 404;
};
var fn2 = function(data) {
  return data.url === 'any_url';
};

var composed = compose(fn1, fn2);

// The line below must return false:
console.log(composed({
  status: 404,
  url: 'foobar'
}));

// The line below must return true:
console.log(composed({
  status: 404,
  url: 'any_url'
}));
```

The advantage of this is that `Array#every` will stop as soon as one return value is `false`.

With ES6+:

```
function compose(...fns) {
  return obj => fns.every(f => f(obj));
}
```

---

**Note:** `compose` is a poor choice of name for this because ["composing functions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) usually refers to passing the result of one function into the other function. I.e. `compose(f, g)(x)` would be the same as `f(g(x))`.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something as simple as

```
function compose(data){
  return fn1(data) && fn2(data)
}
```

this function will return true if all conditions(return values of your functions) are true